# Running Macro from .bat with another Access db open

Tags: vba, batch-file, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a few Access macros automatically periodically throughout the day, I do this by scheduling a batch file to open the relevant Access db and run the macro.

The problem that I am having is, if I am working on another Access database and therefore already have an instance of Access open, the batch file runs but only opens the database containing the macro that is supposed to run and stops. So the macro doesn't run.

Has anyone else had this issue or know how to solve it?

The batch files that task scheduler calls look like this:

```
start /min "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "Q:\TC\DNI_Updater\DNIUPDATER.accdb" /X DailyUpdate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a way to get the `DailyUpdate` macro to run in the second Access session when using `start /min` to open that session.

I'm still unsure whether it's possible, but I gave up and switched to *VBScript* instead.  With that approach, it's easy to start the second Access session minimized and run the macro ...

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim AccessExePath, DbPath, CmdLine, objShell
DbPath = "C:\Users\hans\Documents\test_hfu.accdb"
AccessExePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSAccess.exe"
CmdLine = """" & AccessExePath & """ """ & DbPath & """" & " /X DailyUpdate"
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run CmdLine, 7 ' Minimize. The active window remains active.
```

If this approach is satisfactory, you can use the script file as your scheduled task's *"Start a program"* Action property ...

[image: scheduled task Action property]

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you very much