# How to trigger VBA code in Access when underlying SQL table is updated?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, triggers

## Background

We have a legacy MS Access application that uses MS SQL tables as the backend, and prints a report (product label) on demand based on a user action. This works as expected, and we'd prefer not to change this part.

I have a new standalone (C# Windows Forms) application running on a different PC that performs some mostly unrelated actions, but requires the user to print the above mentioned label towards the end of the process.

## Question

Instead of having the user switch to the legacy Access app on a different PC (which may be at a different location), **how can I trigger the Access VBA that runs the report when data is updated from the standalone C# application?**

## One opproach

I was thinking I could create a table `RequestedLabels` with columns `LabelId`, `PrinterId`. The standalone app would insert a row to request a label, and the MS Access app would query the table at small intervals to see if there are any new labels to be printed for this instance.

However, there are several things I don't like about this approach:

- The label should be printed immediately after the request so my query interval would have to be quite small (1-2s max). Even at 2s the delay would be a nuisance. At higher rates I suspect this could interfere with the MS Access application's responsiveness.
- This would be running on 10-20 machines at at time so the number of queries to the SQL server would be around 20/sec or more.
- The user is only printing labels every few minutes, so most of the processing/network capacity required to do this is wasted.

## A better approach

I was hoping for some way to have changes to the underlying data trigger a Form Event in MS Access, or trigger some VBA function that could print the labels on demand.

## Caveats

The computers are across two subnets separated by a strict firewall and run mixed OSs both on and off the domain. RPC between PCs has proven to be tricky in the past due to the non-uniform setup.

I would prefer a solution that relies on updating the data on the SQL server, or some other MS SQL feature that both the C# and MS Access applications can take advantage of.

### UPDATE:

Since there have been two votes to close, I have refined the wording to focus more clearly on triggering the VBA when the underlying data changes.

Comment: You could just use COM to have your standalone app automate actions on the Access app (e.g., trigger some VBA code using `Application.Run`). Seems a lot better than polling for changes to me.

Comment: @ErikA we have had mixed results with PowerShell remoting due to a wide mix of OSs, domain vs standalone PCs and strict firewalls between the PCs. Also, I would have to test this for every combination of trigger PC and printer PC. That said, I would still like to try this - do you have any example code you can point me to?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a macro in MS Access to send the report to the printer. The report should already have the data you want to print.

Let's say your macro's name is `mcrPrintReport`

Then you can execute MS Access from the command line to open the Access DB file and run the macro like this:

`PathToAccessExe PathToAccessFile /x MacroName`

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE C:\AccessDB.accdb /x mcrPrintReport`

You can then schedule this to run on an interval, maybe every 5 minutes, using the Task Scheduler on a dedicated PC.

See this related question also: [Running Macro from .bat with another Access db open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414756/running-macro-from-bat-with-another-access-db-open)

Comment: I don't think calling and EXE remotely will work for me (I've updated the question to explain why) but if it did, how would I pass the required `labelId` and `printerId` to the macro? I wouldn't be able to poll at 5min intervals since this would be too slow, and faster would have the same types of issues I've already mentioned.